# BTT SKR Mini E3 V3 w/BTT smart filament sensor

Tags: creality-ender-3, bigtreetech, skr-mini-e3, filament-sensor

I'm trying to figure out how to get my **BTT Smart Filament sensor** to work with my printer.

I have looked at [Getting BTT filament sensor to work](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18351/getting-btt-filament-sensor-to-work) and have tried almost everything they did.

Relevant Specs about my printer:

- **Ender 3 (not pro or v2)**
- **BIGTREETECH SKR Mini E3 V3**
- **BIGTREETECH TFT35 E3 V3.0.1**
- **Sensor plugged into `E0-Stop` on the SKR Mini.**
- **Running latest version of Marlin bugfix 2.1.x (last commit 12/5/2022 12:01:08 EST)**
- FYI I also do have **OctoPrint** running and connected to the USB port of the SKR (not sure this matters).

When I follow [BIGTREETECH setup instructions](https://github.com/bigtreetech/smart-filament-detection-module) and several youtube videos for setting up `configuration.h` and `configuration_adv.h`, build the firmware, flash it on the board.  It always starts the print, then immediately stops and reports "Filament out".  I've tried setting the following options:

`configuration.h` options:

```
#define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SENSOR
#if ENABLED(FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SENSOR)
  #define FIL_RUNOUT_ENABLED_DEFAULT true // Enable the sensor on startup. Override with M412 >followed by M500.
  #define NUM_RUNOUT_SENSORS   1          // Number of sensors, up to one per extruder. Define a >FIL_RUNOUT#_PIN for each.
  #define FIL_RUNOUT_STATE     HIGH        // Pin state indicating that filament is NOT present.
  #define FIL_RUNOUT_PULLUP               // Use internal pullup for filament runout pins.
  #define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SCRIPT "M600"
  #define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_DISTANCE_MM 10
  #ifdef FILAMENT_RUNOUT_DISTANCE_MM
    #define FILAMENT_MOTION_SENSOR
  #endif
#endif
```

I've tried flipping

```
#define FIL_RUNOUT_STATE     HIGH
```

to

```
#define FIL_RUNOUT_STATE     LOW
```

but it behaves the same.

Anybody have any ideas? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it appears I have gotten it working.  I guess I didn't flash the firmware after reading that the Smart Sensor requires a minimum of 7 mm of `FILAMENT_RUNOUT_DISTANCE_MM`.  I rebuilt the firmware with the exact settings above and it is now working.  I've tested this by starting a print (calibration cube), I waited for it to complete the first 2-3 layers, then I cut the filament and let it run out.  It did detect the runout and allowed me to reload and continue the print